# Multiplication by zero in an algebra over a field: $0x=0$ for every $x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have an algebra $A$ over a field $F$ and the zero element is $0\in A$. Is it true that $x0=0x=0$ for every $x\in A$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. This holds in all rings, and follows from the distributive law and cancellation in the additive group:
$$0x+0x=(0+0)x=0x.$$

Comment: @Jyrki i.e. $\,0\,$ is the *unique* additive idempotent in an additive group. But $\,0x\,$ remains idempotent, being the image of $\,0\,$ under a group hom $\, r\mapsto rx.\,$ Thus $\,0x = 0\,$ by *uniqueness*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is true, because $A$ is a ring and it is true in rings:

$$0x = (1 - 1)x = x-x = 0$$

Comment: How do you know that $(-1)x = -x$? Typically it's proven by proving first that $0x = 0$...

Answer (score 4):

Another possible proof (without assuming $(-1)x = -x$) :

$$ 0x = (0+0)x = 0x + 0x $$

So $0x$ is the additive identity, making it $0x=0$.